# What is the best way to deal with asynchronously generated parameters iOS8 parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I'm trying to grab an iOS generated parameter for a URL that I'm sending to my server. iOS runs a thread async to get the param. The problem is that when I'm creating the parameters for my URL in my main thread, the iOS `async_param` is sometimes not included in the parameter dictionary that I need (because iOS hasn't finished running its thread).

For example if I'm trying to generate a URL request that includes parameters from two different threads it should look like this `http://myserver.com?param=my_param&async_param=my_async_param`. To generate this I use the following code:

```
-(void) sendURL{
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  //this is my param in the main thread
  [params setObject:@"my_param" forKey:@"param"];

  //get my iOS async param
  [[someIOS8Class sharedInstance] getAsyncParamWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString param)
  {
    [params setObject:param forKey:@"async_param"];
  }];

  [self sendURLWithParameters: params];
  //this is where sometimes the async param does not show up in the URL
}
```

What is the best way to handle this situation if the IOSClass only exist on iOS8?

Comment: Why don't you just call [self sendURLWithParamters:params] at the end of the block instead? That way, you only send the URL when assign_param exists.

Comment: So one thing I forgot to mention is that this iOS class is only available on iOS8. Therefore it won't be able to send the ping if it doesn't have that class.

Comment: That is an entirely different issue than the one we are discussing. Please ask a new question for this.

Comment: Yes I changed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create an error/failure/no-param block and send the url then

```
-(void) sendURL{
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  //this is my param in the main thread
  [params setObject:@"my_param" forKey:@"param"];

  //get my iOS async param
  [[someIOSClass sharedInstance] getAsyncParamWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString param)
  {
    // send the parameter if there's an async param
    [params setObject:param forKey:@"async_param"];
    [self sendURLWithParameters: params];
  } withFailure:^(NSError *error) {
    //Create this error if there's no async param
    [self sendURLWithParameters: params];
  }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a semaphore to wait on any asynchronous code:

```
-(void)sendURL {
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

  //this is my param in the main thread
  [params setObject:@"my_param" forKey:@"param"];

  //get my iOS async param
  dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
  [[someIOS8Class sharedInstance] getAsyncParamWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString param) {
    [params setObject:param forKey:@"async_param"];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
 }];

 dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
 [self sendURLWithParameters: params];
 dispatch_release(semaphore);
 //this is where sometimes the async param does not show up in the URL
}
```

Comment: Hrm - this looks really interesting. How do these work?